# how to fetch from api with nginx and https

Tags: docker, nginx, fastapi

i have some containers in a droplet.  the nginx container serves a containerized app which tries to fetch from a fastapi container.  when that fetch happens, i get:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https:// avnav.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http:// avnav.com/cars'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

**my nginx.conf:**

```
upstream abda_1 {
        server 333.184.52.222:8000;
}
upstream fapi_cars {
        server 333.184.52.222:8001;
}
```

**my default.conf:**

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080 default;
server_name 333.184.52.222 _;
  return 301 https:// avnav.com$request_uri;

        location /cars {
                return 301 https:// avnav.com/cars$request_uri;
        }
}

server {
  listen 4430 ssl;
  listen [::]:4430 ssl;
  server_name 333.184.52.222 www.avnav.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/_cert/etc/letsencrypt/live/avnav.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/_cert/etc/letsencrypt/live/avnav.com/privkey.pem;

  return 301 https:// avnav.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 4430 ssl;
    listen [::]:4430 ssl default ipv6only=on;
    server_name  avnav.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/_cert/etc/letsencrypt/live/avnav.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/_cert/etc/letsencrypt/live/avnav.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/_cert/etc/letsencrypt/live/dhparam.pem;

        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;

    location /media {

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/cors.txt;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/host.error.log warn;
        alias   /usr/share/nginx/static;

        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;

    }

    location /cars {

        proxy_pass http://fapi_cars;
        proxy_set_header Host avnav.com;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/cors.txt;

        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    }
```

**my containers:**

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                   COMMAND               CREATED       STATUS           PORTS                                           NAMES
dfe16ed79c88  docker.io/library/postgres:13.3-alpine  postgres              41 hours ago  Up 41 hours ago  0.0.0.0:5431->5432/tcp                          pg_db1
aae67d66b915  localhost/fastapi:cars                  uvicorn main:app ...  40 hours ago  Up 12 hours ago  0.0.0.0:8001->8000/tcp                          fapi_cars
ca6fd9739fef  localhost/abda:1.0                      gunicorn abd_1.ws...  13 hours ago  Up 13 hours ago  0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp                          abda_1.0
5b395ac70a71  docker.io/library/nginx:latest          nginx -g daemon o...  12 hours ago  Up 12 hours ago  0.0.0.0:4431->4430/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp  nginx.main
```

the website is being served. but when i try to fetch from the fastapi container it tells me it's insecure...

i tried using `proxy_pass https:// fapi_cars;`

but it leads to bad gateway

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an issue with your app? The error is about the request being made against `http` and not `https` - whether the app is reachable by https isn't the issue so far. You might need to have the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header set before your frontend app sees the request.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for the response..i dont think its an issue with the app, since i can visit avnav.com/cars and see the json...?

Comment: No, the error message tells you that the app has been delivered over https, but it attempts to make an request to `http` - and the browser refuses to do that, since that would lower the security level (since it was originally requested on `https`, dropping encryption is usually not what you want). It's about the backend not being requested with https, not about it being served on https or not (which you can test separately by going to the backend with https in front).